# How can I avoid errors when using jquery to append a div containing other javascript?

Tags: jquery, append

I'm using jquery to try to improve the admin user interface on a Microsoft MCMS based website. On load, all of the input fields are in a hidden (with css) div. Then when a dropdown is changed I am using jquery .append to selectively pull items out of the hidden area for the user to enter content into.

My problem is that MCMS inserts javascript in amongst the input fields. When I use .append to move the wrapper divs the javascript within the wrapper causes errors.

The JS is pretty long so I'll just paste the relevant bits below:

```
function setupinputs(passedid) {
    var theinputstoupdate = "Inputs_" + passedid;
    var theinputstoget = "HiddenInputs_" + passedid;
    var selectedwidgettype = $('#'+passedid).val();

    if(selectedwidgettype == "text") {  
        /* get the input wrappers from the hidden area */
        $('#'+theinputstoupdate).append( $('#'+theinputstoget+'_Title') );
        $('#'+theinputstoupdate).append( $('#'+theinputstoget+'_Content') );
    }
}
```

It seems to work pretty well when I test just using some dummy wrappers and input fields but as soon as I implement it with the real MCMS inputs I get errors like:

Message: Unterminated string constant
Line: 112703048
Char: 71
Code: 0

Message: Expected ';'
Line: 112703046
Char: 7
Code: 0

Is it something I am doing wrong in the javascript or (as I suspect) because I am appending wrapper divs containing javascript?

Thanks!

john

Comment: I can't even follow what you are trying to do however, if you are hiding the inputs why don't you just show them rather than this seemingly complex shuffling around?

Answer (score 0):

Do the JavaScript errors happen in edit mode, preview mode or both? I'd suggest you use Firebug and add breakpoints to step through your JavaScript code and find out if MCMS is changing the IDs.